# Extracting e-mails from front-end register

Tags: javascript, automation, frontend

The Swedish government maintains a list of all caregivers in the country. The list is available at:

http://registerplattform.ivo.se/
[Google translation here](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=sv&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=http://registerplattform.ivo.se/&usg=ALkJrhjyqg3NqiSGhPhPj1y007quUVi0AQ)

The visitor can select to filter the list. I do not wish to filter it, I want the entire list.

The e-mail adress to each respective caregiver is not displayed until you click on the caregiver to obtain more info. When doing that, the e-mail is provided in a specific field.

What is the best method to obtain all the e-mail adresses in an automated fashion?

What have I tried?
– I did try various e-mail extractors that are offered as plugins to Chrome, Firefox. None of them seemed to do the job well.
– I did try to manipulate the HTML without any further success.

Is it legal?
Under Swedish law there is nothing prohibiting me from extracting these e-mails.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Asking how to write a scraper is far too broad a question. See the [help]

Comment: I realise that this is not a super simple task but I figured that someone here may know of a simple solution, or perhaps existing tools to overcome this task. But I realise that might be wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the list of all caregiver links, and then load each page and extract the e-mail (using either the position of the element (if the field doesn't change position in each page), or using @ symbol). That's one way, but not quite efficient I admit.